# Cron should be in non-public directory and called with php -f, not wget or curl

Tags: php, security, cron

> Having the Cron script in a public directory allows it to be called by anyone, making it possible to brute-force sending massive amounts of emails (denial of service attack). Cron should be in non-public directory and called with `php -f`, not `wget` or `curl`.

What is the meaning of this and how to solve this?

Comment: As the message says, move the script you use for your crontab outside or the directory of your website that can be reached from the webserver.

Let's say your website is installed in /var/www/sitename.com/www , move the cron outside of the www directory

Comment: Cron job is called b y anyone. I want to it should be called only by server not by noraml user.